# Inverse image a of bounded set is bounded

Tags: general-topology

Knowing that the inverse image of a compact set is compact, prove that the inverse of a bounded set is bounded. ($f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equipped with the usual distance norm-1)
My problem is that I don't know what to do and also , is it true that a set is bounded if it is contained inside an open ball ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a set $A$ is bounded if there exists an open ball that contains it. But notice that open balls are also contained in closed balls, so any bounded set is also contained in a *closed* ball $B$. What do you know about $f^{-1}(B)$, and how do $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ relate to one another?

Comment: $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed and $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$ then $f^{-1}(A)$ is bounded right ?

Comment: You are correct that $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$, and you are correct that $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed, but that's not enough to say it is bounded. How do you know it is bounded?

Comment: If it's compact ?

Comment: Yes, $f^{-1}(B)$ would be bounded if it were compact, since compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are closed and bounded. Do you know that $f^{-1}(B)$ is compact?

Comment: It's compact because B is so ?

Comment: And because $f$ is continuous. If $f$ were not continuous, then the inverse image of compact sets would not necessarily be compact. But if $f$ is continuous, then as you stated in your question, the inverse images of compact sets are compact.

Comment: Good thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded iff it is a subset of a compact set. This follows from Heine-Borel, essentially. This immediately implies what you want: $A \subseteq K$ implies $f^{-1}[A] \subseteq f^{-1}[K]$.